# Probability density and average of distance traveled by falling object

Tags: differential-equations, calculus-and-analysis, probability-or-statistics

```
ClearAll["Global`*"]

 time = Solve[x - (1/2)*g*(t^2) == 0, t]



 position = Solve[x - (1/2)*g*(t^2) == 0, x]

 v = D[(g t^2)/2, t]

 T = Sqrt[2*h/g]

 dt = D[(Sqrt[2] Sqrt[x])/Sqrt[g], x]

 Ptdt1 = dt1/T // PowerExpand

 Ptdt = 
 Replace[Ptdt1, {t -> (Sqrt[2] Sqrt[x])/Sqrt[g], 
   dt1 -> (1/(Sqrt[2] Sqrt[g] Sqrt[x]))*dx}, All]



 rhot = Ptdt/Ptdt[[2]]

 Integrate[rhot, {x, 0, h}]

 Ex = Integrate[x*rhot, {x, 0, h}]

 h = 20



 Plot[rhot, {x, 0, h}, AxesOrigin -> {0, 0}]
```

[image: ss]

Please see my code to do a problem in Griffith's quantum mechanics. But I have a feel that my code is really lengthy and is not general. Is there a way to make this general? or any easy alternatives?
[image: solution]

Comment: Please show us the code text, rather than screenshot of it. If you're having difficulty in formating the code, check the following post: https://mathematica.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1584/1871 and this tool: https://mathematica.meta.stackexchange.com/a/1044/1871

Comment: Edited. Please have a look

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You mainly need `TransformedDistribution`:

```
xrule = DSolve[{x'[t] == g t, x[0] == 0}, x, t][[1]]
(* {x -> Function[{t}, (g t^2)/2]} *)

grule = Solve[x[T] == h /. xrule, g][[1]]
(* {g -> (2 h)/T^2} *)

dist = TransformedDistribution[x[t] /. xrule, 
                               t \[Distributed] UniformDistribution[{0, T}]];

Assuming[{T > 0, h > 0}, PDF[dist, x] /. grule // Simplify]
(* Piecewise[{{1/(2 Sqrt[h x]), x > 0 && h > x}}, 0] *)    

Expectation[x, x \[Distributed] dist] /. grule
(* h/3 *)
```

Answer (score 0):

If a problem can easily be solved analytically, you should not use the PC. You learn more from the analytical calculation.

Given height: h and the acceleration: g, the distance after time t is:

```
s[t_]= 1/2 g t^2
```

That means the maximal falling time is:

```
tmax= Sqrt[2h/g]
```

If we now calculate the mean of s[t] over t:

```
Mean s = 1/tmax Integrate[1/2 g t^2,{t,0,tmax}] 
= 1/tmax 1/2 g tmax^3/3 = 1/6 g tmax^2= h/3
```